# calling a cxxfunction itself recursion

Tags: r, recursion, inline, rcpp, strassen

I have a problem with my cxxfunction in R. And I would like to call this itself, unfortunately, the compiler gives me this error message:

> 'Matmult2' is not declared in this scope

The Problem is also to call `Matmult2` in a cxxfunction.

My original problem is related to the strassen algorithm, I would like to call recursively with RCPP / Inline.
Many thanks for your help!

`

```
Matmult2<- cxxfunction(signature( a="NumericMatrix",b="NumericMatrix"), plugin="RcppArmadillo",includes = rcpp_inc,
  body='

              Rcpp::NumericMatrix verg(a);
              int n = verg.nrow();

              arma::mat A = Rcpp::as< arma::mat >(a);
              arma::mat B = Rcpp::as< arma::mat >(b);

              arma::mat a11 = A(span(0,(n/2)-1), span(0,(n/2)-1));
              arma::mat a12 = A(span(0,(n/2)-1), span((n/2),n-1));
              arma::mat a21 = A(span((n/2),n-1), span(0,(n/2)-1));
              arma::mat a22 = A(span((n/2),n-1), span((n/2),n-1));

              arma::mat b11 = B(span(0,(n/2)-1), span(0,(n/2)-1));
              arma::mat b12 = B(span(0,(n/2)-1), span((n/2),n-1));
              arma::mat b21 = B(span((n/2),n-1), span(0,(n/2)-1));
              arma::mat b22 = B(span((n/2),n-1), span((n/2),n-1));


              if ( n  < 780) return Rcpp::wrap( A * B );


              arma::mat P1(Matmult2(a11,(b12-b22)));
              arma::mat P2(Matmult2((a11+a12),(b22)));
              arma::mat P3(Matmult2((a21+a22),(b11)));
              arma::mat P4(Matmult2((a22),(b21-b11)));
              arma::mat P5(Matmult2((a11+a22),(b11+b22)));
              arma::mat P6(Matmult2((a12-a22),(b21+b22)));
              arma::mat P7(Matmult2((a11-a21),(b11+b12)));

              arma::mat c11((P5+P4-P2+P6));
              arma::mat c12((P1+P2));
              arma::mat c21((P3+P4));
              arma::mat c22((P5+P1-P3-P7));

              mat C1 = join_rows(c11, c12);
              mat C2 = join_rows(c21, c22);
              mat C = join_cols(C1, C2);

              return Rcpp::wrap( C );
```

')

`

Comment: You really should only define Rcpp functions inline that have rather short and simple source code. I'd advise you to use a separate C++ source file. That is not more difficult to handle (in particular if you use an IDE) and you get the additional advantage of syntax highlighting and other tools.

Comment: Good advice, and it is also recommend to switch from inline to Rcpp Attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do *direct* recursion because the glue code we insert creates a wrapper function that is called---but you do not want the wrapper to be called recursively, you want your function to be called.  So you would need too: a wrapper called from R, and a C(++)-only recursive function that is
called from your wrapper, and which calls itself.

It also works if you switch to Rcpp Attributes. Here we use the standard bearer of recursive functions, the Fibonacci sequence:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction("double fib(double n) { if (n < 2) return n; return(fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)); }")
R> sapply(0:10, fib)
 [1]  0  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
R>
```

(And I use `double` instead of `int` as the latter overflows earlier.)